# searching exact word using LIKE

Tags: php, mysql

Please help...
I need to be able to search an exact words in my database.., I've already used different methods..

#### Method 1

```
$param2 = "SELECT * from item WHERE prodname REGEXP '[[:<:]]($param)[[:>:]]'
           order by CASE WHEN instr(prodname, '$param') = 0 then 1 else 0 end,         
           instr(prodname, '$param') ASC";`
```

This is working really good but when I tried searching words with `\` or `"` it returns an error. I've already used `htmlspecialchars` and `mysql_real_escape_string` but the problem still exist..

#### Method 2

```
$param2 = "WHERE prodname LIKE '$param %' OR prodname LIKE '% $param'
           OR prodname LIKE ' $param%' OR prodname LIKE '%$param '
           OR prodname LIKE '% $param %'
           order by CASE WHEN instr(prodname, '$param') = 0 then 1 else 0 end, instr(prodname, '$param') ASC";`
```

This is also working good but when I type the exact product eg "STAMP PAD INK (RED)" it returns the result "NOT FOUND" but it shows when I only type "STAMP PAD INK".. for some reason It works when I add `'%$param%'` but when I type an exact word ex. "INK" the word "WRINKLED" also shows and I dont want that.

I can't use fulltext..

Comment: Stop using the MySQL extension, it is deprecated. Use PDO or MySQLi instead and implement using prepared statements with parameter binding. Then your first method should work fine, regardless of what characters exist in the product name

Comment: SQL built-in functions are generally not meant for what you need. I think, you may want to write your own function to fulfill this concrete requirement of yours. Also a *word* in a list of words should have a specific pattern as a separator (a space as can be seen in your case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For method 2 : 
To get the exact product, use: LIKE '$param'

The % character matches any number of characters, even zero characters, but there is still the space characters in '% $param %', for instance.

More info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using the PHP function addslashes() for $param as in:

$param = addslashes($param);

This will make method 1 work.

mysql_real_escape_string's behavior is based on the default character set and I don't know which one you are using. Since it's not working for you, then addslashes probably will.

BTW, you may want to look further into how to use fulltext indexing because REGEXP has the potential of becoming mindnumbingly slow as the database grows. And method 2 that you show will perform very slowly, always.

Comment: The following line of code happens before the select query.  You will keep your $param2 exactly as you typed it above.

Comment: when I type "STAMP PAD INK (RED)" as soon as I type the "(" parenthesis it returns an error when I close it., (type the closing parenthesis) it returns no result found..

Comment: I did forgot to mention that my search query is in an external php file and the keywords are pass through a javascript.., I dont know if it has anything to do with the error but still when I directly assign the keyword to a variable for testing nothing is shown not even an error...

Comment: this is the error: Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource...